# Suppose that $V ⊂\mathbb R^n$ is a subspace. How to show that $V$ is a normal subgroup of $\mathbb R^n$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, vector-spaces

> Suppose that $V ⊂\mathbb R^n$ is a subspace. that $V$ is a normal subgroup of $\mathbb R^n$.
>   A bit confused on how to approach this.

Comment: Do you possibly mean $V$ is a subspace of $\mathbb R ^n$?

Comment: Yes, I believe that's what the question possibly means.

Comment: Just note that when you have a vector space $V$ over a field $F$, as one of the axioms states, $V$ itself should be an abelian group. In this case $\mathbb R ^n$ is your abelian group which is endowed with a vector space structure over the field $\mathbb R $. Since $V$ is a subspace of $\mathbb R ^n$, it should be a subgroup of $\mathbb R ^n$, which is an abelian group.
But, there is a simple exercise to show that every subgroup of an abelian group is normal. So, you are done.

Comment: I was overthinking this waaaay too much. Thank you, Kaveh!

Comment: It's clearly a subgroup. Since $\Bbb R^n$ is abelian, every subgroup is normal.

Answer (score 0):

It's a subspace, which means it has a group law under which the group is closed (the law comes from the "sub" part, and closure is the "space" part). It's a normal subgroup because $\mathbb{R}^n$ is abelian, and any subgroup of an abelian group is abelian.

Alternately, you could directly verify the group law and abelian nature of the subspace.